# Killing vector and one-form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, supersymmetry, vector-fields, supergravity

p. 21 in this paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.0247)

$V$ is Killing vector, where $V^2 = −4b\bar{b}$, which means it is timelike Killing vector.

The authors say:

> From $V^2 = −4|b|^2$ and $V = ∂_t$ as a vector we get $V_t = −4|b|^2$,

My question here is how did the authors set $V_t$ equal to this value?

They add,

> From $V^2 = −4|b|^2$ and $V = ∂_t$ as a vector we get $V_t = −4|b|^2$, **so that $V = −4|b|^2(dt+σ)$ as a one-form, with $σ_t = 0$.**

Why did they assume that?

Comment: 1. Please include all relevant information into the question. What is $b$, what is $\sigma$, why is $V$ timelike, what manifold are we even on? 2. If $V$ is an ordinary vector field, $V^2 = -4\lvert b \rvert^2$, $V = \partial_t$ and $V_t = -4\lvert b\rvert^2$ do not make any sense if $V_t$ is meant to be the temporal component of $V$. *By definition*, $V_t = 1$ if $V = \partial_t$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind - If $V = \partial_t$ then $V^t = 1$ not $V_t$.

Comment: @Prahar you're absolutely right since we're talking about dual maps. Maybe it is a typo from the authors or something deeper than that :S.

Comment: @Prahar: Ah, yes, sorry. Beyond-formulas: It's a bit weird in the first place to claim to be able to write a *vector field* as a *1-form*, since 1-form are the duals to vector fields. But if they mean that the dual form to $V$ can be written as such, then the claim follows directly from $V_t = -4|b|^2$: $V^\flat = V_\mu\mathrm{d}^\mu = V_t \mathrm{d}t + V_i\mathrm{d}x^i = V_t (\mathrm{d}t + \frac{V_i}{V_t}\mathrm{d}x^i)$ and defining $\sigma = \frac{V_i}{V_t}\mathrm{d}x^i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question here is how did the authors set $V_t$ equal to this value?

On page 21 the authors say: "Let us choose coordinates
$(t, z, x_i)$ such that $V = \partial_t$ and $i = 1, 2$."

So they chose the coordinates such that $V=\partial_t$, which means $V^t=1$. Note that the other components of $V^\mu$ are zeros. Next we have
$$V^2=V_\mu V^\mu=-4|b|^2=V_t V^t+V_{x_1}V^{x_1}+V_{x_2}V^{x_2}+V_{z}V^{z}=V_t*1,$$
from which you find $V_t=-4|b|^2$. Here we used $V^{x_i}=V^z=0$.

> Though what I don't get is their requirement that σt be equal to zero and why did they place a dt next to it. Why did they assume that?

$\sigma$ is a general one form on coordinates $x^i, z$, which means $\sigma=\sigma_{1}dx^1+\sigma_2 dx^2+\sigma_3 dz$, note that later they use the gauge freedom to set $\sigma_z=0$. They chose the coordinates to fix $V_t$ and the rest it is the most general one form on $x^i$. For example, the most general one form on coordinates $t,x^1, x^2,z$ is $\alpha=\alpha_0 dt+\alpha_1 dx^1+\alpha_2 dx^2+\alpha_3 dz$. Compare it to their expression for $V$ (after (4.7)) and you will see that they chose only the first components, the rest is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid this doesn't answer my question. Maybe what ACuriousMnid mentioned above solved my issue. I can't see if your answer is adding anything to ACuriousMind's answer. Is it?

Comment: @Beyond-formulas Well, he made several comments from the mathematical point of view and, I think, he did not answered your questions directly. My answer is direct and simple, also it does not contradict his :) But everything he said is right.

Comment: $V=\partial_t$ means $V^t=1$, not $V_t=1$! To get the object with lower index you need to use the metric $V_t=g_{t\alpha}V^\alpha$.

Comment: Ah sorry. My bad there. Then can you please explain the authors claim when they said: "From $V^2 = −4|b|^2$ and $V = ∂_t$ as a vector we get $V_t = −4|b|^2$". Where did $V_t = −4|b|^2$ come from?

Comment: @Beyond-formulas If the metric such that $g_{t\alpha}=0, \alpha={x^i,z}$ then $V^2=V_t V^t=-4|b|^2=V_t*1$, now you can easily solve this equation on $V_t$.

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks. Let me ask you two questions to get the full picture. Why did you write $g_{t\alpha}=0$? Is this given someplace I didn't see in the paper? And how from it did you deduce that if $g_{t\alpha}=0$ then $V^2=V_tV^t= ...$? Please, I ask you kindly to answer those if possible in your answer so I can choose it as a best answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33842/discussion-between-g3n1uss-and-beyond-formulas).

Comment: Hey @g3n1uss, I wanna ask you a fast question. On page 21, the author said, "Let us choose coordinates
$(t, z, xi)$ such that $V = ∂_t$ and $i = 1, 2$. The metric will then be independent of t." Why did they conclude that the metric will be independent of t?

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics $V=\partial_t$ means that $V$ is a Killing vector along $t$, which means that the metric is independent of $t$. In general, if the Killing vector has the form $V^{y}=const$ it means that the metric is independent of $y$.

Comment: I see!! ok thanks. A very very stupid question that I can't help but ask: in (4.8) there is a $dt$ in the first term. So in a way or another there is a $t$ dependence eventhough people are saying that the metric is time independent, bizarre right?

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics I will give you an example, when I write $X=A dt+ B dz$ it means nothing but $X_t=A, X_z=B$. It is just the compact way to write vectors, instead of using smth like $X=(A,B)$.

Comment: Hey, how are you? I have asked a question related to the same paper through this link http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227771/geometry-of-spacetime-and-spinor-bilinears, I would much appreciate if you could take a glance at it. Anything out of your expertise in supergravity will definitely help. @g3n1uss