# Geometry of spacetime and spinor bilinears

Tags: string-theory, spacetime, supersymmetry, spinors, supergravity

In this paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.0247) p.20, the author says in the section titled **Geometry of spacetime** the following:

> In order to obtain the spacetime geometry, we consider the spinor bilinears
>   $$V_{\mu}= D(\epsilon, \Gamma_{\mu}\epsilon) \hspace{2cm} B_{\mu}=D(\epsilon, \Gamma_5\Gamma_{\mu}\epsilon) \hspace{2cm}(1.1)$$
>   whose nonvanishing components are
>   $$V_+ = \sqrt{2}b\bar{b},\hspace{.5cm} V_− = −\sqrt{2}, \hspace{2cm}B_+ = \sqrt{2}b\bar{b},\hspace{.5cm} B_− =\sqrt{2}.$$
>   As $V^2 = −4b\bar{b} = −B^2$, $V$ is timelike and $B$ is spacelike. Using eqns. (4.1) - (4.4) (therein), it is straightforward to show that V is Killing and B is closed.

What is the importance of these two vectors?

Comment: I do not really understand your question, but probably you are asking why do we need bilinear/forms and how do we construct them, is this right?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/227555/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equations on bilinears follow directly from the Killing spinor equations. The latter are all you have, there is no additional equations.

For example, look at Appenedix A (in particular in A.1) [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0409174.pdf). You can construct a lot of different bilinears, but the only bilinears you need to write down the solution are (A.17) and all the following equations (A.18-A.21) follow directly from the Killing spinor equations (A.16).

Comment: Again, you only have the Killing spinor equations, which represent some restrictions on Killing spinors. Next, (if you want) you can construct some vectors/forms from Killing spinors, for example, you can construct a vector $K_\mu=-\bar{\epsilon}\gamma_\mu \epsilon$. It is not a Killing vector, just a vector and to prove that it is Killing you need to play with Killing spinor equations.

Comment: But the authors in both papers only plugged $\epsilon$ in your $K_{\mu}$ and proved it is equal to the Killing vector without any playing of any sort. I quote your paper p. 6: "One then constructs various forms by using spinor bilinears. These forms have **interesting properties**. For example, we can construct a **Killing vector**, which we assume to be non-zero." They say also, "There is another interesting form which is a closed one form". So, they are confidently telling us this is a property of these bilinears, they happen to tell you how your Killing vector and your closed form look like

Comment: @Beyond-formulas When they say "First we observe that $K_\mu$
is a Killing vector" it means - "We spent several hours/days to prove it and here is the result". 

"We observe" means "prove it yourself, it is easy".

Comment: @Beyond-formulas It is not weird, their draft was probably ~ 200 pages and they had to cut smth, because nobody will read 200 pages long paper. So they cut calculations that could be done in a reasonable time.

Comment: I said it is weird because there's no point in shedding lights on that. However, I am having the feeling that this has to do with G-structure method to solve KSE. What would really satisfy me is to know whom was the first to recognize that K. Vector that you find from manipulating KSE can also be found by solving directly a bilinear. Those people would have a definite explanation as in why would we really care to know that those quantities relate.

Comment: The goal is to find some restrictions on the metric, for example, existence of some Killing vectors, but it is not smth that must be there. The authors have been playing with KSE for awhile and found some relations that restrict the metric, that is it. G-structure has nothing to do with it. "Vector that you find from manipulating KSE can also be found by solving directly a bilinear." this sentence does not make any sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33947/discussion-between-g3n1uss-and-beyond-formulas).

Comment: Helllo! Can you please have a look at my problem here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230323/difficult-proving-how-t-transforms-like-a-vector-here?noredirect=1#comment500650_230323 (My problem is that I am not being able to derive this mathematically from what is given) I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Beyond-formulas I was going to look at your question, but you already removed it :)